# Cannot upgrade/un-install m2eclipse plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

I have Eclipse 3.6 with m2eclipse (Maven's plugin for Eclipse) 1.1, it works.

And now I want to try m2eclipse version 1.4, I upgrade it directly and find I cannot see Maven in any menu. Then I try to uninstall and re-install it but I always get this message and Eclipse doesn't install anything.

```
Your original request has been modified.
"m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse" is already present because other installed
software requires it.  It will be added to the installed software list.
```

Finally, I try to search all files contain "m2e" and delete them from Eclipse's directory, but still get the same message, any suggestion to un-install m2eclipse?

ps: I use Eclipse Help > About eclipse > Installation details to un-install and restart to make sure m2e is not in Eclipse before re-install. I also use -clean parameter but still the same.

Comment: What about upgrading Eclipse first? Your installation is 3 years old...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the m2e plugin in Eclipse Help > About eclipse > Installation details. You should find all the m2e to uninstall.

Edit :
You could also reload eclipse with the `-clean` option so any cached data used by the OSGi framework and eclipse runtime will be wiped clean

Comment: Thanks, but I already try to un-install it from it and I cannot see it in the "Installation details" anymore. But when I try to install it again, I still get the same message.